# I'm trying to put validation but not working in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't understand how to put a validation in `jQuery` so anybody who can solve this question please help me.

```
$(function(){

        $("#btn").click(function(){
        var b=prompt("Enter your link");
        $("a").attr("href",b);      
        if($("b").val()=='')
        {
            var con=confirm("Please Enter your link");
            if(con==true)
            {
                var b=prompt("Enter your link");
                $("a").attr("href",b);

            }else
            {
                var pr=confirm("Please Enter your link");
            }

        }

    });
```

**The html coding is also available below:**

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
        <div id="div1">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><h3>Facebook</h3></a>

                <img src="1.jpg" alt="My Images">

        </div>
<button id="btn">Attribute(a)</button>
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm waiting for solutions thanks.

Comment: you want to set url validation??? and If dont insert link to ask more 2 times???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="div1">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><h3>Facebook</h3></a>
      <img src="1.jpg" alt="My Images">
    </div>
    <button id="btn">Attribute(a)</button>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

/////////////////////

```
$(function(){
  $('#btn').on('click',function(){
      var b=prompt("Enter your link");
      var link = $("a").attr("href",b);
    if(link.val()==''){
       var con=confirm("Please Enter your link");
       if(con==true){
           $("#btn").trigger('click');
       }
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: While this code may solve the author's problem, a good answer typically explains _why_ they had a problem as well as providing code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is work one...
if I **understand** you well
you have to change `$("b").val()==''` because `b` is **not** an element on document. It is only parameter 
**and also** it nicer to do it in this way `onclick="func()"` **instead of**  `$('#btn').on('click',function(){...}` but it is for your choice

```js
function func(){
        var b=prompt("Enter your link");
        $("a").attr("href",b);      
        if(b=="")
        {
            var con=confirm("Please Enter your link","");
            if(con!="")
            {
                var b=prompt("Enter your link");
                $("a").attr("href",b);

            }else
            {
                var pr=confirm("Please Enter your link");
            }

        }
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com"><h3>Facebook</h3></a>
  <img src="1.jpg" alt="My Images">

</div>
<button onclick="func()" id="btn">Attribute(a)</button>
```

Comment: Tell me for more help